# ¿Cómo alinear 3 imágenes en el centro contenidas en un div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

lo que pasa es que estoy haciendo un ejercicio de drag and drop sobre canecas de reciclaje. Dichas canecas las quiero alinear en el centro de mi documento (en una misma línea, izquierda centro y derecha). Con el código que llevo solo consigo alinearlas en el centro pero de forma vertical y en diferentes líneas. Agradecería su ayuda, soy nuevo en este mundo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```html
<center><h1> Arrastrar y soltar </h1></center>

<center><p> Caneca azul </p>
    <div class="img" id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="imagenes/azul.png" width="100px" height="90px">
</div>


<br>

<p> Caneca verde </p>
    <div class="img" id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="imagenes/verde.png" width="100px" height="90px">
</div>

<br>

<p> Caneca gris </p>
    <div class="img" id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="imagenes/gris.png" width="100px" height="90px">
</div> 
</center>
    <br /> <br />

<center><div id="x">
<img src="imagenes/botella.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="70">
</div>

<div id="y">
<img src="imagenes/carton.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2" width="88" height="70">
</div>

<div id="z">
<img src="imagenes/aluminio.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag3" width="88" height="70">
</div>
</center>
```

Comment: Buenas, te aconsejo que mires css, más concretamente flexbox, Puedes definir una fila y repartir elementos de forma uniforme, por ejemplo puedes tener esas 3 canecas en una sola fila, simplemente englobandolas en un mismo div con una id o una clase concreta (a la cual le asignes propiedades css de flexbox) intentaré dejarte un ejemplo claro en las respuestas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para lograr lo que deseas debes crear un contenedor (`div`) por cada caneca, para luego asignarles un estilo `display: inline-block` y se ubiquen una al lado de la otra:

```css
.caneca > div{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<center><h1> Arrastrar y soltar </h1></center>

<center class="caneca">
    <div>
      <p> Caneca azul </p>
      <div class="img" id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <img src="imagenes/azul.png" width="100px" height="90px">
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <p> Caneca verde </p>
          <div class="img" id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          <img src="imagenes/verde.png" width="100px" height="90px">
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <p> Caneca gris </p>
      <div class="img" id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <img src="imagenes/gris.png" width="100px" height="90px">
      </div> 
     </div>
</center>
    <br /> <br />

<center><div id="x">
<img src="imagenes/botella.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="70">
</div>

<div id="y">
<img src="imagenes/carton.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2" width="88" height="70">
</div>

<div id="z">
<img src="imagenes/aluminio.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag3" width="88" height="70">
</div>
</center>
```

Otra forma muy fácil de lograrlo es usando [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.caneca{
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: row;
}

.caneca > div{
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<center><h1> Arrastrar y soltar </h1></center>

<center class="caneca">
    <div>
      <p> Caneca azul </p>
      <div class="img" id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <img src="imagenes/azul.png" width="100px" height="90px">
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <p> Caneca verde </p>
          <div class="img" id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          <img src="imagenes/verde.png" width="100px" height="90px">
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <p> Caneca gris </p>
      <div class="img" id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <img src="imagenes/gris.png" width="100px" height="90px">
      </div> 
     </div>
</center>
    <br /> <br />

<center><div id="x">
<img src="imagenes/botella.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="70">
</div>

<div id="y">
<img src="imagenes/carton.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2" width="88" height="70">
</div>

<div id="z">
<img src="imagenes/aluminio.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag3" width="88" height="70">
</div>
</center>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ya pude alinearlas con la primera solución. Disculpa el atrevimiento, pero cómo hago para que cada vez que quiera soltar un elemento a a cada caneca, me muestre un mensaje que diga "residuo correcto" en caso de que el residuo a reciclar pertenezca a cada caneca, o en el caso contrario que diga "residuo no perteneciente". Gracias de antemano.

Comment: @JorgeHernández me alegra mucho que te haya servido la solución, en cuanto a tu nueva inquietud debes crear una nueva pregunta y mostrar que has intentado para lograr dicha validación, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Eso que pides se puede hacer con `flexbox`de la siguiente forma:

**HTML**

*Supongamos que queremos poner los 3 contenedores alineados*

```
<div id="canecas">
    <div class="item">
        <p> Caneca azul </p>
        <div class="img" id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
            <img src="imagenes/azul.png" width="100px" height="90px">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <p> Caneca azul </p>
        <div class="img" id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
            <img src="imagenes/verde.png" width="100px" height="90px">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <p> Caneca azul </p>
        <div class="img" id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
            <img src="imagenes/gris.png" width="100px" height="90px">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

*Pues en una página de estilos css haremos lo siguiente*

```
.canecas{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items:center;
}
```

Y esto debería bastar.

**ESPERO QUE TE HAYA SERVIDO :)**

Comment: Muchas gracias.